# Getting php file attributes through java code

Tags: java, php

I have a php code file and i have to get all the attributes defined in that class using java code. Is there a way of doing so other than travesing through the file.

Answer (score 0):

Look for a parser generator. My personal favorite is [antlr](http://www.antlr.org/).